# How to keep wifi sharing while Mac is sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite, macbook-pro-retina

I only have "Turn display off later" bar, I thought it should have another "Turn computer to sleep later" bar too... I don't know if this is a change of Yosemite... 
It is supposed to look like this:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119975/keep-wi-fi-connection-while-asleep

BUT, mine DOES NOT have the "computer sleep" bar, I only have "display sleep" bar...
This is so weird....

Now how do I set when to put my Mac to sleep? And how do I keep wifi sharing while the screen goes dark?

Answer (score 1):

Check the checkbox, "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when display is off".

Then your Mac will stay on all the time (even if it turns the display off), and you'll probably pay more in extra electricity costs in a year than if you'd bought yourself a cheap Wi-Fi router.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Nosleep, I use it a lot when i use my Plex server on my laptop, just remember to turn it off when you're using it normally otherwise it'll obliterate your battery